# Can you have multiple http-equiv meta properties?

Tags: html

I don't really understand what it does, but it is set in my project to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

I want to force compatibility mode in IE8 off, cos people keep turning it on and it breaks stuff. It's software used on the intranet where everyone has IE8.

I read that I should put this in:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

to force it off. However, should I replace the first line with this one, have both, or do something else entirely?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just put those two lines in the head, don't combine them.

You can have as many meta http-equiv tags as you want.

The sames goes for normal meta tags.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, don´t worry. You may have multiple http-equiv lines.
In fact, on this case what you are doing is setting 2 different variables:

1. `Content-Type = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"`
2. `X-UA-Compatible = "IE=EmulateIE8"`

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
   ```

In my pages I am setting my X-UA-Compatible as:

```
<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=100\" >
```

I think IE=100 has the same effect as IE=EmulatesIE8

Answer (score 0):

put the X-UA-Compatible tag at the top of the head section of your document as it needs to be here. Content-type is telling the browser what the document content is and should be placed after t.